# SharePoint Online - custom ribbon tab on all pages

Tags: sharepoint-online, client-object-model, sharepoint-addin, office-365, ribbon

Is there a way to make custom tab available on all pages of SharePoint Online website?
For SharePoint Farm solution you can register a Delegate Control and activate it on a server side like this:

```
SPRibbon ribbon = SPRibbon.GetCurrent(this.Page);
if (!ribbon.IsTabAvailable("Ribbon.CustomTabExample")) {
    ribbon.MakeTabAvailable("Ribbon.CustomTabExample");
}
```

But in SharePoint Online we don't have server side code. Is there any other way to activate the tab on SharePoint Online? Maybe there is a way to call MakeTabAvailable from javascript?